# pygame image disappears instantly

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make an image appear in a pygame window if I press on a key on my MIDI keyboard. The image appears for a second and then disappears.

```
going = True
while going:
    screen.fill(white)
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for e in events:
        if e.type in [QUIT]:
            going = False
        if e.type in [KEYDOWN]:
            going = False
            events = pygame.event.get()
        if e.type in [pygame.midi.MIDIIN]:
            screen.blit(IMG, (50, 60))
        pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

And no this doesn't work either..

```
if e.type in [pygame.midi.MIDIIN]:
    screen.blit(IMG, (50, 60))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with Python or Pygame, but with correct usage: The code inside the `while going` loop is executed *multiple times per second*, but the event (MIDI key press) is only raised once.

You need to change the program logic to trigger some kind of state, for example `show_image`: when the MIDI event is detected, set `show_image = True` and in the while loop, display the image only if `show_image == True` (independent of any events triggered in this loop iteration)

The basic logic should be like this:

```
going = True
show_image_1 = False
show_image_2 = False
...
while going:
    screen.fill(white)
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for e in events:
        if e.type in [QUIT]:
            going = False
        if e.type in ...:
            show_image_1 = True
        if e.type in ...:
            show_image_2 = True
        ...
    if show_image_1:
        screen.blit(IMG_1, (50, 60))
    if show_image_2:
        screen.blit(IMG_2, (50, 60))
    ...
    pygame.display.update()
```

Of course, if you have more than one image, you should have some more clever logic instead of an `if` for each image.

Comment: I think I have tried doing basically that. I tried if e.type in [pygame.midi.MIDIIN]: NoteList.append(MIDI_key) and then do a loop to print an image based on the MIDI_key but it still disappears. And if I try to do it outside of a loop or an if statement, than I get index out of range error because it tries to blit the image before NoteList() has any values

Comment: I added some more explanations

Comment: Ok I actually did both this time, NoteList.append() and show=True, then if show==True..... and it worked. But now the previous image disappears whenever I try to blit another one based on another MIDI input

Comment: I only have one image but I need to print it in the pygame window multiple times based on each MIDI input. I have a set of functions that translate the MIDI input into x,y coordinates btu what's happening is that I can only blit one image at a time it seems

Answer (score 0):

The code written by you should instantly disappear the image as while loop terminates and pygame clears the image instaneously.
I think what you were trying to do was that on pressing down key new image should load so you would not make going false.

```
going = True
while going:
    screen.fill(white)
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for e in events:
        if e.type in [QUIT]:
            going = False
        if e.type in [KEYDOWN]:
            events = pygame.event.get()
        if e.type in [pygame.midi.MIDIIN]:
            screen.blit(IMG, (50, 60))
        pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I tried taking out the false assignments that didn't work. Also you changed nothing in the code.

Comment: sorry I changed i guess it was not saved I have edited. please check if it works.